# PHP short way to echo string?

Tags: php, echo, curly-braces, curly-brackets

In `PHP` we `echo` strings this way :

```
echo 'string';
```

But i saw `PHP` frameworks like `Laravel` and scripts `echo` strings using `Curly Brackets` :

```
{string}
```

How i can do that without using any `PHP` framework?

It's not necessary to use `Curly Brackets` if there is other way to short echo!

I prefer code examples.

Comment: Laravel uses the template engine `Blade` (by default), thats why the syntax is not the same as in php.

Comment: I don't use PHP anymore, but perhaps you could look through the document for a specific match with Regex, then echo anything between the `{}`.

Answer (score 7):

PHP has a few methods to print strings, such as (but not limited to) `print`, and `echo` or just shorthand `<?= "str" ?>`.
The bracket print that you ask about from laravel is not per say in php.
That is from a template engine called `Blade`.

So the `{}` way of printing stuff is not possible in php.
You will have to stick to the standard ways or use a template engine!

Comment: But i saw a php script (not a framework) using that way to echo {string} and also working in html files! thanks for your information.

Comment: Was the name of the php file: somename.blade.php? :)

Comment: Nope, it was named like file.html

Comment: Its possible to make the engine look for php or html files (without the blade part) as blade templates. I have not tried this, so I'm not 100% sure on how it works, and I would not recommend this, cause its a lot more easy to see that its a blade template if its in the file name! :) `View::addExtension('php', 'html');`

Answer (score 5):

You can short echo by

`<?= $variable; ?>` when you open a new php tag

or you use, as described in your question a framework such as laravel - that's pretty much it

What you can do, but I'm not really sure if it's a good idea - write a function like:

```
function x($string) {
    echo $string;
}

x('Test');  // will output Test
```

Comment: Away from talking about Laravel, i saw a php script using that way to echo {string} .. i think it's a way of coding or a plugin/engine but i really don't know what is it! the function solution is good by the way!

Comment: Even though its possible to create a shorter function, I would not recommend doing so, it will make the code harder to read and understand, which is not a good thing. (And yes, I noticed that the answer said it might not be a good idea, I'm just supporting that!)

Comment: Thanks! Not sure about the {}, I haven't seen it yet outside of laravel and MVCs

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't do that with PHP. PHP provides language constructs to output to standard output, etc. PHP doesn't provide a pre-processor. Most template frameworks are a pre-processor meaning that they convert your `{<STRING>}` into an `echo $x` statement.

So either create your own template framework, or stick to PHP's API.

Comment: about creating my own template, i just wanted to do that echo way {string} not creating a php framework from scratch, and i swear god i saw a php script (not framework) using that way to echo {string} and also working in html files! thanks for your information.

Comment: Link to PHP script...?

Comment: Here's the script, go to the "Templates" directory and open for example "links.html" you'll see he's using {} to echo :
http://goo.gl/JWGPL6

Comment: Sorry, here's the link of the script :
http://www31.zippyshare.com/v/17537696/file.html

Answer (score 0):

After researching i found a `Template Engine` called [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) that allows me to echo using `Curly Brackets`

First i created 2 files `index.php` , `template.html`

Then i moved the folder `/libs` that i downloaded from the [template page](http://www.smarty.net/download) to my script directory

and in my `index.php` i required the `Smarty.class` file

```
require_once "libs/Smarty.class.php";
```

then i called the `Smarty` class :

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
```

after that i pushed the variable :

```
$smarty ->assign("name",'Amr');
```

and i displayed the template file `index.html`

```
$smarty ->display("template.html");
```

at the end i wrote in the `index.html` `<p>{$name}</p>` and it outputted : `Amr`